# Store inverted index in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I am using Spark to create an inverted index (or more a "posting list", so the order of the postings is important), which looks a bit like this

```
|   key   |  postings                                    |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   "a"   |  1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 21, 25                    |
|   "b"   |  7, 12, 21, 24, 28, 31, 37, 48, 51, 91       |
|   "c"   |  1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 17, 21, 38, 39, 40, 47     |
```

Note the key is e.g. a string, the postings is a sorted list of e.g., integers. I will later use the postings list and iterate over it multiple times (and hopefully very efficiently).

I am wondering what the best option is to create such a dataframe in Spark and finally store it to Parquet. Do you suggest to e.g. use nested structs? Or rather to use an array for the postings (though what should I do if I wanted to store more than only a single id, but an id and a distance, i.e. a tuple of integer and float)? Or would you suggest not to use such a posting list at all and go for a flat structure (e.g. key, posting where the same key appears multiple times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a list. It's going to be fairly easy to collect a list of simple values like an `IntegerType`. Like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a",1,1.1),("a",3,2.3),("a",4,1.0),("b",7,4.3),("b",12,11.11),("b",21,0.01)
).toDF("key","posting","distance")

val aggregatedDf1 = df.groupBy("key").agg(collect_list(col("posting")) as "postings")
```

It's going to be more difficult to do `collect_list` on a complicated `StructType`, because Hive aggregation functions only work on simple types.

To aggregate a `StructType`, you need to create a `UDAF`. The `UDAF` API is a bit tedious, so you can cheat a little, and aggregate the columns into two lists, and then use a simple `UDF` to `zip` the two lists, like this:

```
val zipper = udf[Seq[Tuple2[Int,Double]],Seq[Int],Seq[Double]]((a,b) => a.zip(b))

val aggregatedDf2 = df.groupBy("key").agg(
  collect_list(col("posting")) as "postings",
  collect_list(col("distance")) as "distances"
).withColumn("postings", zipper($"postings", $"distances")).drop("distances")
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the difference is between UDAF and UDF?

Comment: UDF = User Defined Function and it is used to apply some function to every row of a dataframe. UDAF = User Defined Aggregate Function and is used to do custom calculations on grouped data (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/apache-spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights.html).

Comment: As you can see, the API for a `UDF` is pretty lightweight -- you only need a single line of code to create it. On the other hand, a `UDAF` takes a lot of special incantations to make it work. See here: https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/spark-custom-udaf-example/